# Detect Tapping of "Touch to return to call" in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

Is there a way to detect if a user tapped the "Touch to return to call" (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m9xi.jpg)? Maybe some kind of a delegate method, or a parameter like in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score -3):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var observer: NSObjectProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { [unowned self] notification in
            // do whatever you want when the app is brought back to the foreground
        }
    }
}
```

Just this code in you callKit viewcontroller class and check when user will return back to app by taping "Touch to return to call"

Comment: This will always be called when you go back to the app even if you don't tap "Touch to return to call". (e.g. tapping the app icon)